# how to call web service with authentication using web request

Tags: c#, web-services, webrequest

I have web service which need authentication.

```
public class WebService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    public AuthHeader Authentication;

    [WebMethod]
    [SoapHeader("Authentication", Required = true)]
    public void Hello(string name)
    {
        string result = "";
        if (Authentication.Username == "test" && Authentication.Password == "test")
        {
            result = "hello " + name;
        }

        Context.Response.Write(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(result));
    }
}

public class AuthHeader : SoapHeader
{
    public string Username;
    public string Password;
}
```

I used to call the web service like this

```
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
        WebResponse ws = request.GetResponse();

        string result = string.Empty;
        using (System.IO.StreamReader sreader = new System.IO.StreamReader(ws.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            result = sreader.ReadToEnd();
        }
```

but I don't know how to do it with authentication. How to set the header of the web request for authentication?

Answer (score 0):

According to this msdn resource: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest(v=vs.110).aspx `WebRequest` has a property called `Credentials`.

> When overridden in a descendant class, gets or sets the network
>   credentials used for authenticating the request with the Internet
>   resource.

Try to use it and see if it works.